# On the coordinate ring of an affine algebraic variety over a field that is not algebraically closed.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I do hope I'm translating all of the terms correctly to English!

As a part of a course in algebraic geometry we proved the theorem: If $X\subset\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{k}^n$  is an affine variety, $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraicly closed field, $f\in A(X)\backslash\{0\}$ and $X_f = X\backslash \mathcal{Z}(f)$ then
$\mathcal{O}(X_f) = A(X)_f = \{{\frac{g}{f^n}\mid g\in A(X), n\geq 0}\}$

As a note, the proffesor added that the statment isn't correct over non algebraicly closed fields, and for example he observed the function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ which is regular in $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{R}^1$ but isn't a polynomial.

I don't understant how the fact that the given function isn't a polynomial is a contradiction to the statment in the theorem (I do understand the regularity). Can anyone explain, please?

EDIT: adding appropriate defenitions
Let $X\subset\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{k}^n$ be an affine variety, $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraicly closed field, then

$A(X)=\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(X)$.

For any point $P\in X$ we define $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}=\{\frac{f}{g}\mid f,g\in A(X), g(P)\ne0\}$
and for an open set $U\subset X$, $\mathcal{O}(U)=\bigcap_{P\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$

Comment: Take $f=1$ you'll get that $O(X)$ is the coordinate ring of the affine variety, this is true if $X$ is the whole $\overline{k}$ points of our variety but not when restricting to the $k$ points.

Comment: When $f=1+x^2$ over $k=\mathbb{R}=X$, there are no vanishing points, so $X_f = X = \mathbb{R}$ and $O(X_f) = O(X) = O(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}[x]$. Since it's not a polynomial, $1/(1+x^2) \in \mathbb{R}[x]_f - \mathbb{R}[x] = O(X)_f - O(X_f)$. If the theorem held in this case, this difference would be empty.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson - Maybe here lies my problem. Why is O(R)=R[x]? Shouldn't it be rational functions in general?

Comment: (for an affine variety defined over $\Bbb{R}$) then $X(\Bbb{R})$ is not open in $X$ because the latter either means $X(\Bbb{C})$ or the prime ideals of the coordinate ring depending on if you like the scheme viewpoint or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about the notation, but let me guess.  The claim is that the formula

F1. $\mathcal{O}(X_f)\cong \mathcal{O}(X)_f$

does not hold when $k$ is the field of real numbers.

If $k[x]$ is the polynomial ring in one variable with $k$ the field of real numbers and $I:=(0)$ the zero ideal, let $X:=Z(I)=\mathbb{A}^1_k$. Let us assume there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong k[x]$. Let $f:=x^2+1$. It follows $Z(f)$ is the empty set, hence $X-Z(f)=X$ and $\mathcal{O}(X_f)=\mathcal{O}(X)=k[x]$. But $k[x]_f\cong k[x,t]/(tf-1) \neq k[x]$. Hence $\mathcal{O}(X_f)\neq \mathcal{O}(X)_f$ in this case.

If you give the definition of an algebraic variety $X$ and the ring $\mathcal{O}(X)$ over a non-algebraically closed field $k$, it will be easier to comment. Hartshorne assumes in Chapter I that the base field $k$ is algebraically closed.

If you define $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}})$ as the set of functions with the following property (P1):

P1. $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for any point $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is an open subset $U(p)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and two polynomials $p(x),q(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that the restriction $f_{U(p)}$ of $f$ to $U(p)$ satisfies $f_{U(p)}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$,

then it follows the function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is a regular function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}})\neq \mathbb{R}[x]$. Hence the answer depends on the definition of $\mathcal{O}(X)$. If $z=a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$ with $b\neq 0$, it follows
the polynomial $p_z(x):=(x-z)(x-\overline{z})=x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial - it has no real roots.
Hence if you use definition P1 to define the ring of regular functions, it follows the function $f(x):=\frac{1}{p_z(x)}$ is a regular function. If $S\subseteq A:=\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the set of polynomials on the form $p(x):=\prod_{z_i\in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}} (x-z_i)(x-\overline{z_i})$ it follows $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset, and the ring of fractions $S^{-1}A$ is a sub-ring of $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}})$. Hence with definition P1 it follows the ring $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}})$ is much larger than $A$.

Your addition: "EDIT: adding appropriate definitions. Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_K$ be an affine variety, $K$ is an algebraically closed field, then $A(X)=K[x_1,…,x_n]/I(X).$"

My comment: This is the definition given in Hartshorne, Chapter I for algebraically closed fields. You need to include the definition used for non-algebraically closed fields.

Real algebraic geometry is an independent field. There is a version of Hilbert's "Theorem of zeros".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krivine%E2%80%93Stengle_Positivstellensatz